# Разбить документ на части с использованием регулярного выражения

Tags: java, readfile

Читаю документ в массив, из него пытаюсь с помощью регулярного выражения разбить на части и разложить данные в модель City.
Читаемый документ выглядит так:

```
241;Тырныауз;Кабардино-Балкария;Северо-Кавказский;21000;1934
242;Чегем;Кабардино-Балкария;Северо-Кавказский;17988;
243;Багратионовск;Калининградская область;Северо-Западный;6399;1336
244;Балтийск;Калининградская область;Северо-Западный;32670;1626
```

и проблема в том, что в 242 строке отсутствует 6-й столбик и соответственно при разложении в модель он в 6й столбик кладет 1й столбик следующей строки, выскакивает ошибка OFB
Помогите написать регулярку, чтобы она пропускали или нулевое значение ставила полю.

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        City city = new City();

        InputStream readFile = new FileInputStream
                ("src/main/resources/readFile/city_ru.csv");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(readFile);


        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] arr = sc.nextLine().split(";");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

                city.setName(arr[1]);
                city.setRegion(arr[2]);
                city.setDistrict(arr[3]);
                city.setPopulation(Integer.valueOf(arr[4]));
                city.setFoundation(arr[5]);
            }
```

Модель сама

```
public class City {
  
    private String name;
    private String region;
    private String district;
    private Integer population;
    private String foundation;
```

Comment: Если Вам был дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> в 6й столбик кладет 1й столбик следующей строки

Не-а. arr[5] вообще не существует. Просто проверяйте длину массива!

```
city.setFoundation(arr.length >= 6 ? arr[5] : "else");
```

P.S. метка [регулярные-выражения](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) лишняя. Ими  тут и не пахнет)

Comment: Боже как все просто! Благодарю, все работает!